# Multiple StreamBuilder that using same stream work incorrectly?

Tags: flutter, dart

Let say I have code like this

```
class ScreenA extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenA();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Stream<List<Order>> ordersStream = Order.stream;
    return Column(
      children: [
        StreamBuilder(
          stream: ordersStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
              return Text(snapshot.data!.toString());
            } else {
              return const LoadingCircle();
            }
          },
        ),
        TextButton(
          child: Text('to ScreenB'),
          onPressed: () => MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>
                ScreenB(ordersStream), // pass stream to another screen
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ScreenB extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenB(this.ordersStream);

  final Stream<List<Order>> ordersStream;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: ordersStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
          return Text(snapshot.data!.toString());
        } else {
          return const LoadingCircle();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This seem to work, but when `ScreenA` already got data, in `ScreenB` `snapshot.ConnectionState` will mark as `ConnectionState.waiting` until `ordersStream` emit new value (It should get data as same as `ScreenA`).

For example;

at second 0: created `ordersStream`

at second 1: `ordersStream` emit value `[Order1,Order2]`

at second 5: I press button to go to `ScreenB` <- `ordersStream in ScreenB` should get `[Order1,Order2]` too, but it didn't give any value and has state `ConnectionState.waiting`.

at second 10: `ordersStream` emit value `[Order3,Order4]` <- `ordersStream in ScreenB` get value now.

I tried using `StreamProvider`, but it doesn't fit my code project, how to make this work correctly without `StreamProvider`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the stream key inside the builders.

```
StreamBuilder(
          stream: ordersStream, //add stream here
          builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
           return Container();            
        }
 )
```

**Edit**

You can pass the current data along with the stream and in the second screen you can set the initial data with the data that you recieved from screen 1

```
StreamBuilder(
 initialData: YourCurrentDataFromScreen1,
 stream: streamHere,
 builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
           return Container();            
        }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add stream argument. I just edited my post

Comment: Are you getting the same issue again?

Comment: I didn't have problem you mentioned. I just forgot to add it when writting sample code. my problem is in ScreenB stream do not give me value until it emit new value. Maybe you not understand, my English isn't good. Feel free to ask more.

Answer (score -1):

This is how `broadcast stream` works.

> You can start listening to such a stream at any time, and you get the events that are fired while you listen.

See [Broadcast streams](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams#broadcast-streams).